Custom class via {% element %} template django allauth
I'm trying to use the following scheme below:
example of my template elements/h1.html
{% comment %} djlint:off {% endcomment %}
{% load allauth %}

<h1>
    {% default slot %}{% endslot %}
</h1>

It is possible to declare the h1 in another template, via
{% element h1 %}
     {% trans "Sign In" %}
{% endelement %}

for example, do I pass the name of a class? This way I can customize forms and other elements via .css.
<h1 class="login-title">
Sign-in

</h1>


Possible, yes. But this will result in a lot more processing time, and Django's rendering engine is already quite inefficient. and does not allow for much stream-like processing
